# Multi label encoding for classes with duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

How can I n-hot encode a column of lists with duplicates?

Something like `MultiLabelBinarizer` from sklearn which counts the number of instances of duplicate classes instead of binarizing.

Example input:

```
x = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['b', 'c'], ['c','c']])
```

Expected output:

```
    a   b   c
0   2   1   0
1   0   1   1
2   0   0   2
```

Comment: For pyspark, you can probably use `pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer`, see one of my examples (you will need to use the default: **binary=False**): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010126/pyspark-string-array-of-dynamic-length-in-dataframe-column-to-onehot-encoded/58012725#58012725

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written a new class **`MultiLabelCounter`** based on the [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L770) code.

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np

class MultiLabelCounter():
    def __init__(self, classes=None):
        self.classes_ = classes

    def fit(self,y):
        self.classes_ = sorted(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(y)))
        self.mapping = dict(zip(self.classes_,
                                         range(len(self.classes_))))
        return self

    def transform(self,y):
        yt = []
        for labels in y:
            data = [0]*len(self.classes_)
            for label in labels:
                data[self.mapping[label]] +=1
            yt.append(data)
        return yt

    def fit_transform(self,y):
        return self.fit(y).transform(y)
```

```py
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['b', 'c'], ['c','c']])

mlc = MultiLabelCounter()
mlc.fit_transform(x)

# [[2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I have been trying to extend it to work on multiple specified columns of a dataframe instead of a single series by using a dictionary of dictionaries with if statements for the mapping. Can you see a more efficient way?

Comment: May be am not understanding your concern correctly. You can use `columnTransformer` for extending this to multiple columns. Probably you can add more details in your question.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to add two more features:
1. The ability to do `.fit(df[['columnA','columnB']]` on multiple features like [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py#L79)
2. An inverse operation to map the columns back to the original representation like [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.inverse_transform).


These are so only one transformer is required for a dataset instead of one per column.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work so you don't have to do it haha. I'd be happy to just get pointers too

Comment: I would recommend asking this as a separate question with good example. I would be happy to help!