# Pyspark string array of dynamic length in dataframe column to onehot-encoded

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, transformer-model

I would like to convert a column which contains strings like:

```
 ["ABC","def","ghi"] 
 ["Jkl","ABC","def"]
 ["Xyz","ABC"]
```

Into a encoded column like this:

```
 [1,1,1,0,0]
 [1,1,0,1,0]
 [0,1,0,0,1]
```

Is there a class for that in pyspark.ml.feature?

Edit: In the encoded column the first entry always corresponds to the value "ABC" etc. 1 means "ABC" is present while 0 means it is not present in the corresponding row.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use [CountVectorizer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer), Below is an example:

**Update:** removed the step to drop duplicates in arrays, you can set `binary=True` when setting up CountVectorizer:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([
        (["ABC","def","ghi"],)
      , (["Jkl","ABC","def"],)
      , (["Xyz","ABC"],)
    ], ['arr']
)
```

create the CountVectorizer model:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol='arr', outputCol='c1', binary=True)

model = cv.fit(df)

vocabulary = model.vocabulary
# [u'ABC', u'def', u'Xyz', u'ghi', u'Jkl']
```

Create a UDF to convert a vector into array

```
udf_to_array = udf(lambda v: v.toArray().tolist(), 'array<double>')
```

Get the vector and check the content:

```
df1 = model.transform(df)

df1.withColumn('c2', udf_to_array('c1')) \
   .select('*', *[ col('c2')[i].astype('int').alias(vocabulary[i]) for i in range(len(vocabulary))]) \
   .show(3,0)
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|arr            |c1                       |c2                       |ABC|def|Xyz|ghi|Jkl|
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|[ABC, def, ghi]|(5,[0,1,3],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]|1  |1  |0  |1  |0  |
|[Jkl, ABC, def]|(5,[0,1,4],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]|1  |1  |0  |0  |1  |
|[Xyz, ABC]     |(5,[0,2],[1.0,1.0])      |[1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]|1  |0  |1  |0  |0  |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to expand the list in a single column to multiple `n` columns (where n is the number of items in the given list). Then you can use the [OneHotEncoderEstimator class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoderestimator) to convert it into One hot encoded features.

Please follow the example in the documentation:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0.0, 1.0),
    (1.0, 0.0),
    (2.0, 1.0),
    (0.0, 2.0),
    (0.0, 1.0),
    (2.0, 0.0)
], ["categoryIndex1", "categoryIndex2"])

encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=["categoryIndex1", "categoryIndex2"],
                                 outputCols=["categoryVec1", "categoryVec2"])
model = encoder.fit(df)
encoded = model.transform(df)
encoded.show()
```

[OneHotEncoder class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder-deprecated-since-230) has been deprecated since `v2.3` because it is a stateless transformer, it is not usable on new data where the number of categories may differ from the training data.

This will help you to split the list: [How to split a list to multiple columns in Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789489/how-to-split-a-list-to-multiple-columns-in-pyspark)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The part with the onehotencoder is good. I edited my question. My problem is that I don't know how many entries I have and that the order can be random. If I use the splitting solution you linked I would in worst case get a column1 which can contain all values. And a column2 with maybe all values again.

Comment: I think you will have to convert the list to the same length and split it anyway, unless you can write a `udf` or a generic python function to one hot encode your list which you can apply through the same udf.

Comment: @pissall, if the OP needs an array instead of vector, he might have to use udf anyway.