# NLP: Apply CountVectorizer to column containing a list of features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

I want to apply `CountVectorizer` to column that contains a list of words and phrases. In other words, the corpus is not a string but a list. The problem is that `CountVectorizer` or any other related function I encountered expect a string as an input. It doesn't make sense to join the list into one string and them tokenize because some phrases contain 2 words. Any ideas?

example:

```
ID      corpus
1       ["Harry Potter","Batman"]
2       ["Batman", "Superman", "Lord of the Rings"]
```

desired result:

```
ID   Harry Potter    Batman    Superman    Lord of the Rings
1    1               1         0           0
2    0               1         1           1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tokenized your sentences already, `CountVectorizer` might not be required for this.

I have written a `MultiLabelCounter()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371409/multi-label-encoding-for-classes-with-duplicates/57375810#57375810), which can solve your problem.

```py
import pandas as pd
x = [["Harry Potter","Batman"], ["Batman", "Superman", "Lord of the Rings"]]

mlc = MultiLabelCounter()
mlc.fit_transform(x)
# [[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]

mlc.classes_
# ['Batman', 'Harry Potter', 'Lord of the Rings', 'Superman']
```

[image]